# Getting data from facebook javascript API

Tags: facebook

Maybe it's too late, but how would one go about getting the response variable into the space outside of the facebook api function. I had hoped to do something from the FB.api call, but that doesn't work.

```
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
  console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
});
```

Comment: Since this is an asynchronous call, you should handle the response from within the callback. You can f.e. pass it to other functions from within there if you like.

Comment: I understand that (I think). However, since the facebook initialization is done prior to page load working with this data is almost impossible as any function called will either be run prior to page load as well or at some unreliable time within the loading process.

Is it really not possible to get this data into a post load environment?